# SSIS Export Error: Column "***" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types

Tags: ssis, export

I'm trying to export some data from SQL SERVER to EXCEL, with SSIS, and got error on all columns like

[Excel Destination [2]] Error: Column "Contact Id" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.

I tried to change data type in the OLE DB Source to be 'Unicode string [DT_WSTR]' or 'Unicode string [DT_STR]', but I get same error no matter which one I use.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS Convert Between Unicode and Non-Unicode Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547539/ssis-convert-between-unicode-and-non-unicode-error)

Comment: @Nambu12 Thanks. But in the issue you mentioned, he used NVARCHAR in sql,  mine was from the table which has VARCHAR. Also, whether I tried convert of not ([DT_WSTR] or [DT_STR]) i got same error

Comment: I used data conversion and now it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using data conversion task and data types as [dt_str] or [dt_wstr]