# SSIS 'Column' and 'Parameter' cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, oledbcommand

I have a Data Flow Task that does this:

1. From two different OLE DB Sources, run a SQL Command to select some data
2. Merge Join the two DB sources
3. Lookup to a different SQL DB Source, check if the data already exists or not
4. Based on Lookup Match Output vs. Lookup No Match Output, run INSERT statement with different input parameters.

[image]

The problem is, during the INSERT, it's complaining about Column 'a' and Parameter '1':

> Cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.

I looked up this StackFlow suggestion to change the Column 'a' to (DT_WSTR) string. However the column has already been set to that data type.

- [SSIS Convert Between Unicode and Non-Unicode Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547539/ssis-convert-between-unicode-and-non-unicode-error)

Column 'a' is actually not grabbing directly from the database, but instead a constant value

```
SELECT 'abc'+ FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyyMMdd') + 'zz208874' AS a
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Verify and compare the statements of the 2 OLE DB Commands. What are the datatypes of the target columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem is how the query is parsed in the `OLEDB Command` and how the SQL Server database engine defined the parameter data type.

Try using a `CAST()` function to avoid that:

```
 SELECT CAST('abc'+ FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyyMMdd') + 'zz208874' as VARCHAR(255)) AS a
```

Or, if you are looking to convert to unicode:

```
SELECT CAST('abc'+ FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyyMMdd') + 'zz208874' as NVARCHAR(255)) AS a
```

or, you can define strings as Unicode:

```
SELECT N'abc'+ FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyyMMdd') + N'zz208874' AS a
```

For more information about parameter data type parsing issues, you can check my answer on the following question:

- [Date calculation with parameter in SSIS is not giving the correct result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54289456/date-calculation-with-parameter-in-ssis-is-not-giving-the-correct-result/54297521#54297521)