# SSIS convert non Unicode to Unicode but the text is error

Tags: unicode, ssis, fonts, non-unicode

I have a package that copy data from Oracle database to SQL database.
I used data conversion to convert DT_STR -> Unicode string, but my data has font error (It is Vietnamese)

[image]

```
empnm           |
----------------+
BUI TH？ TH？？NG  |
CAO V？N TIN    |
CHU TH？ THOA    |
LE NG？C HOA     |
L？？NG V？N VINH  |
NGUY？N V？N THANH|
T？ V？N PH？？C    |
```

Oracle:

```
EMPNM   VARCHAR2    50
```

SQL:

```
empnm   nvarchar    50
```

I can't find anyone has same issue as me. Can you please give me some advices? Thanks

I tried this: [SSIS Convert Between Unicode and Non-Unicode Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547539/ssis-convert-between-unicode-and-non-unicode-error)

I expect text data is normal

```
EMPNM           |DUMP(EMPNM,1016)                                                                               |
----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
BÙI THỊ THƯƠNG  |Typ=1 Len=19 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 42,c3,99,49,20,54,48,e1,bb,8a,20,54,48,c6,af,c6,a0,4e,47   |
CAO VĂN TIẾN    |Typ=1 Len=15 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 43,41,4f,20,56,c4,82,4e,20,54,49,e1,ba,be,4e               |
CHU THỊ THOA    |Typ=1 Len=14 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 43,48,55,20,54,48,e1,bb,8a,20,54,48,4f,41                  |
LÊ NGỌC HOÀ     |Typ=1 Len=15 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 4c,c3,8a,20,4e,47,e1,bb,8c,43,20,48,4f,c3,80               |
LƯƠNG VĂN VINH  |Typ=1 Len=17 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 4c,c6,af,c6,a0,4e,47,20,56,c4,82,4e,20,56,49,4e,48         |
NGUYỄN VĂN THÀNH|Typ=1 Len=20 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 4e,47,55,59,e1,bb,84,4e,20,56,c4,82,4e,20,54,48,c3,80,4e,48|
TẠ VĂN PHƯỚC    |Typ=1 Len=18 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 54,e1,ba,a0,20,56,c4,82,4e,20,50,48,c6,af,e1,bb,9a,43      |
```

Comment: Please *do not* use images of code (nor result data) in your [mcve]. Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code. Post a hexadecimal dump in case of (partially) binary content.

Comment: Not too sure what is done when. But if you have DT_STR in any part of this. I would expect it cannot read Vietnamese thus would give an ASCI equivalent, then when converting to DT_WSTR, it is already a broken character. so ensure if is mapped as Unicode from the source connection down to the destination.